# Cloud Foundry Webinar Promo Code : How to Apply to Existing Account?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Attended Cloud Foundry webinar today and received promo code for (IIRC) "free 2 GB account", but I have already registered previously with Cloud Foundry.

My question is how can the benefit supplied by the promo code be applied to my already existing account (assuming that there is, in fact, some differential benefit) ?

Comment: I think you'd have to ask the people who run Cloud Foundry.

Answer (score 2):

hope you enjoyed the webinar. Current accounts are all limited to 2gb, so you can't, say add the other 2 to the first ones to get a 4gb account.

Benefiting from larger accounts will be available with our commercial offering.

In the meantime, what you can of course do is create 2 separate accounts, assuming none of your apps need more than 2gb by themselves (which would be a good thing, presumably)